# openCV make error

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I've been trying to run make on the recent release of openCV (2.4.3) but I've been having problems.  I've created a build folder in the openCV directory and ran the following commands:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -js
```

I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib
[ 35%] Building CXX object modules/video/CMakeFiles/opencv_video.dir/src/bgfg_gaussmix.cpp.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentOrder", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentPattern", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentRow", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentSpeed", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetCurrentTempo", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_packet in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetLength", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_header in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetMessage", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_header in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
  "_ModPlug_GetName", referenced from:
     _modplug_read_header in libavformat.a(libmodplug.o)
```

There's more but the rest of the message is the similar to that.
It looks like the linker is having a hard time with highgui.

I've received a similar error when I (somehow miraculously) had openCV installed previously (I deleted the former installation) when trying to run code using XCode

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the cause of this particular problem. However, I found a workaround that works for my situation. I disabled ffmpeg and it seems to compile ok. I cleaned out my build directory and ran cmake with the option -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF

Comment: what are the consequences of turing ffmpeg off?